# Get parameter from a search form without any entity attached

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am creating simple search form that will query and render data using Doctrine LIKE expression.I am confused how to get the parameter like this

```
$name = 'San Francisco China';
```

In the controller i created a simple form

```
 public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = array();
    $form= $this->createFormBuilder($data)
        ->add('name_city', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Search Here',
            'error_bubbling' => true,
        ))
        ->add('search', 'submit')
        ->getForm();



    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $data = $form->getData();
    }
    $name = $request->request->get('name_city');//this confused me
    //$name = 'Beijing Angeles';//this will work

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $city = $em->getRepository('Bundle:City')->searchCity($name);


    return $this->render('Bundle:City:list.html.twig', array(
        'city' => $city, 
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

In this case, the $name variable is passed to the searchCity method as the argument

```
public function searchCity($name)
{

    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.name LIKE :name_city')
        ->setParameter('name_city', '%'.$name.'%')
       // ->orderBy('v.dateCreated', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

//list.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %} 

{% block body %}
  {{ form(form)}}

{% for city in city %}
  {{ city }}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

This will not work since all city name are displayed during page load. If i manually add a value to the $name, e.g $name = 'Beijing Washington', search works.Whats the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the setting the default `name_city`, you could do this:

```
$data = array(
    'name_city' => 'Beijing Angeles'
);

$form= $this->createFormBuilder($data)
    ->add('name_city', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Search Here',
        'error_bubbling' => true,
    ))
    ->add('search', 'submit')
    ->getForm();

// The rest of your code
```

Then, get the city name like:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
$data = $form->getData();
$name = $data['name_city'];
```

You might notice that I removed the `POST` check. That's because search forms are traditionally set to `method="get"`, because of history/bookmarks. So, in your example, you would never check for `POST` but `handlerRequest()` each  and every time.

Hope this helps...

Feel free to correct me if I misunderstood the intention here ;)

Comment: what is the purpose of $data in the very first part of the code?I thought it the purpose is to initialise an array.

Comment: When you initially visit the search form, that is form was not submitted, you still need to pass the city to your repository function. So, we read the form data (city) and pass it on...